# ¿Cómo reemplazar vocales ? JAVA

Tags: java

Reemplazar  vocales:    consiste    en  que el  usuario ingresa una palabra o   frase   y   la  vocal   que quiere  poner   y   el  programa    le  muestra dicha   cadena  con todas   las vocales cambiadas   por la  indicada,   por ejemplo:    si  la  frase   ingresada   es: ESTE    ES  MI  PASATIEMPO      con la  vocal   i,  el  programa    mostrará:   ISTI    IS  MI  PISITIIMPI

Tengo este código pero reemplaza toda la cadena de texto.

```
String cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese una palabra o una frase ");
 String vocal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese la vocal por la cual quiere reemplazar "+ "las letras de la palabra o frase ingresada ");
msj = cadena.replace(cadena, vocal);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msj);
```

Comment: Deberías poner tu código si es que has intentado algo, de lo contrario será complicado ayudarte. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

No dices si hay que respetar mayúsculas o minúsculas, ya que eso influirá en el resultado, pero esto funciona perfectamente:

```
String regexp="[aeiouAEIOU]";
System.out.println(cadena.replaceAll(regexp, vocal));
```

Si tuvieses que respetar mayúsculas y minúsculas, partes la expresión regular en 2 y haces dos replaceAll, el segundo sobre el resultado del primero, y cada una de ellas con una expresión regular